# Do we have to enable or disable PCI interrupts on every layer, or only at the closest to hardware?

Tags: operating-system, interrupt, device-driver, interrupt-handling, pci

I'm implementing a PCIe driver, and I'd like to understand at what level the interrupts can be or should be enabled/disabled. I intentionally do not specify OS, as I'm assuming it should be relevant for any platform. By levels I mean the following:

- OS specific interrupts handling framework
- Interrupts can be disabled or enabled in the PCI/PCIe configuration space registers, e.g. COMMAND register
- Interrupts also can be masked at device level, for instance we can
  configure device not trigger certain interrupts to the host

I understand that whatever interrupt type is being used on PCIe (INTx emulation, MSI or MSI-X), it has to be delivered to the host OS.

So my question is really -- do we actually have to enable or disable interrupts on every layer, or it's sufficient only at the closest to hardware, e.g. in relevant PCI registers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling interrupts at the various levels usually has completely different purposes.

Disabling interrupts:

- **In the OS** (really, this means **in the CPU**) - This is generally about avoiding race conditions. In particular, if state/memory corruption could occur during a particular section of code if the CPU happened to be interrupted, then that section of code will need to disable interrupt handling. Interrupt handlers must not acquire normal locks (by definition they can't be suspended), and they must not attempt to acquire a spin-lock that is held by the thread currently scheduled on the *same* CPU (because that thread is blocked from progressing by the very same interrupt handler!) so ensuring data safety with interrupt handlers can be tricky. Handling interrupts promptly is generally a good thing, so you want to absolutely minimise such sections in any code you write. Do as much of your interrupt handling in *secondary interrupt* handlers as possible to avoid such situations. Secondary interrupt handlers are really just callbacks on a regular OS thread which doesn't have any of the restrictions of a primary interrupt handler.
- **PCI/PCIe configuration** - It's my understanding this is mainly about *routing* interrupts, and is something you normally do once when your driver loads (or is activated by a client) and again when your driver unloads (or is deactivated). This may also be affected by power management events. In some OSes, the PCI(e) level is actually handled for you when you activate PCI device interrupts via higher-level APIs.
- **On-device** - This is usually an optimisation to avoid interrupting the CPU when it doesn't need to be interrupted. The most common scenario is that an event happens on the device, so an interrupt is generated. The driver's primary interrupt handler checks the device registers if the driver needs to do any processing. If so, it *disables* interrupts on the device, and schedules the driver's *secondary* interrupt handler to run. The OS eventually runs the secondary handler, which processes whatever information the device has provided, until it runs out of things to do. Then it *enables* interrupts again, checks once more if there's any work pending from the device and if there are none, it terminates. (If there are items to process in this last check, it re-disables interrupts and starts over from the beginning.) The idea is that until the secondary interrupt handler has finished processing, there really is no point triggering the primary interrupt handler, and a waste of resources, if additional events arrive, because the driver is already busy processing the event queue. The final check after re-enabling interrupts is to avoid a race condition between an event arriving and re-enabling interrupts.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: this helps to understanding, thanks. Could you clarify the following: if a driver opts to use e.g. INTx interrupts paradigm, is it supposed to disable MSI/MSI-X interrupts delivery (as it is possible via MSI/MSIX capability PCI registers)? Does the same apply to disabling INTx when MSI is selected? In case of Linux it looks like it is done by PCI layer when calling pci_msi_enable/pci_msix_enable. Is this optional and depends on OS?

Comment: The standardised PCI capability registers are *usually* taken care of by the OS's PCI support. When your driver claims the device and registers its interrupt handler with the OS, you usually have the ability to choose MSI or MSIX. The OS needs to know what you're using so it can call your handler at the appropriate time, so it also does the PCI config. But check with your OS's documentation/source code if there is anything it expects you to do. If your device has custom MSIX vector selection registers for different types of events you'll need to deal with those in your driver. Hope that helps?

Comment: thanks, this makes it clearer. Is there a requirement in PCI/PCIe specs for disabling INTx when MSI/MSIX is active? I was looking for this in specs, but failed to find. After all, I suppose only one interrupt mode should be active.

Comment: Sorry, my experience with MSI has been on OS X, where the IOPCIFamily drivers deal with interrupt routing, all you do is request MSI and it'll fallback to classic IRQ lines if device/host combo don't support it. I'd have to look it up how it works in detail!